# Executing a process and getting caller's interface

Tags: c#, interface, process

Its better if I describe this using code. I have the following interface:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    void DoSomething();
}
```

I have two Windows Form applications, called MyFirstApp and MySecondApp. Both applications implement the IMyInterface interface. MyFirstApp is calling MySecondApp like so:

```
var p = Process.Start("MySecondApp");
```

Everything if working as expected. Now what I want to do is, after MySecondApp launches, I'd like to be able to figure out how it was started (in this case, it was started by MyFirstApp) and if it was started my MyFirstApp, I'd like to be able to get a reference to the interface and call DoSomething() inside MyFirstApp. So the psuedo-code for MySecondApp will look like this:

```
if (this was started by MyFirstApp)
{
    IMyInterface firstApp = (IMyInterface)<handle to MyFirstApp>;
    firstApp.DoSomething();
}
```

My question is, how do I do this in C#?

Comment: You must be coming from a COM background. Applications don't have interfaces in .NET. In fact, there's no such thing as a handle to an application.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - So does that mean its impossible for an application to execute an interface method from another application?

Comment: Yes. The question doesn't even make sense. What are you trying to accomplish? Why would these be separate applications?

Comment: @JohnSaunders - I'm sorry if this is coming off sounding stupid. I'm just trying to understand. Isn't this how plug-in architectures work? But instead of separate applications, they are DLL files? Don't they do exactly what I'm trying to do? They load the DLL in memory and execute the appropriate interface methods? Only difference for me is instead of a DLL being loaded into memory, its an executable being started by Process.Start?

Comment: This isn't the sort of thing that typically happens across processes. Usually, it's just within a single process. Also, if you're against reinventing the wheel, take a look at the [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx)

Comment: @JohnSaunders - I know about MEF. I was just using the plug-in example as an example. What I'm actually trying to do is send a notification from MySecondApp to MyFirstApp that notifies it to shut down. MySecondApp will be updating DLL files that MyFirstApp uses, so I want to send a signal to MyFirstApp to shutdown, then MySecondApp should update the DLLs as necessary.

Comment: In this case, consider using WCF. MyFirstApp would host a management service with at least the one operation, ShutDown. You could add other management operations as desired.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Thank you. That is what I'll do. If you make your comment into an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you want to have one application manage another application. You can do this by having the managed application host a simple WCF service which has operations like "ShutDown", "Configure", "GetStatistics", etc.

Depending on the scope of the management, you can use one of the Named Pipes bindings, which only work on a single machine, or one of the TCP  bindings, which you might want to use within your Intranet, or one of the Http bindings, which can be used across the Internet.

All of these cases would use the exact same service code.